# storing JSON data using to html5 webstorage

Tags: html

I am using HTML5 web storage for storing data locally. I want to store the JSON data into database. For that i am converting the JSON as string using JSON.stringify(obj).

But, I could not able to storing the data. can any body suggest the best approach?

```
var customerStr = JSON.stringify($scope.indexData);
var db = openDatabase('customerDB', '1.0', 'customer DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

      db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (id unique, userid, customerdata VARCHAR)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (id, userid, customerdata) VALUES (1, 2, customerStr)');            
        console.log('<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>');

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some confusion as posted code and title differs.

Code  you have posted is creating a table if not exists and inserting  a record.

however create table line is not correct as datatype of userid is missing.
try to run this sql in query analyser to find out syntax error

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (id unique, userid, customerdata VARCHAR)'
```

Take a look here for how to use [HTML5 WEb storage](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_storage.htm)

you can use localstorage as below.

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}

// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```